# What are the limitations of disabling nodeIntegration in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In Electron's [docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) it allows us to enable or disable nodeIntegration (disabled by default). When disabled, does it disable the whole application from using node.js features or just a certain process (main process, renderer process and custom modules)?

I heard there was security issues when using nodeIntegration. What are they?

My application will likely only be used by myself as a personal thing. It will include a `localhost` server, a custom API, a remote MongoDB database accessed through my custom API and utilizing an external API. If node.js is disabled, how would I even develop this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Only renderer process will affected. Main process will have access to node.js api all time.
2. Exposing node.js api into renderer process reveals security issue to local system - this means any XSS in renderer process can have system access (like `fs`, or `child_process`). Normally renderer process is sandboxed so XSS is limited to its scope.
3. Even after disabling node integration, `preload` script can access node.js all times. Preload script can be used to prepare interface to renderer process exposes only needed access / limit, verify input attacks.

Comment: So it would be good to leave it disabled and require custom modules in the main process where the window is created to handle the APIs and localhost server without any of that being accessed and vulnerable to XSS while handling normal Javascript in the renderer process?

Comment: `it would be good to leave it disabled and require custom modules in the main process`: yes, the implementation may vary based on your application architecture. using preload is quick way to go, or you could use localhost if your main process already have it but personally do not recommend lot about localhost server in main process.

Comment: The only OS that I'm making this for right now is Windows. My server isn't actually in the main process. It gets required in it from a custom module that starts the express server. What would you recommend and why? I need to be able to utilize [MongoDB](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) to access the remote database.